# User permission requirements to log into vSphere Client for iPad and vCenter Mobile Access

Tags: vmware-esxi, ipad

I was just wondering what the minimum permission requirements for a user for to be able to log into the vSphere Client for iPad and vCenter Mobile Access. The clients are connecting to a plain ESXi box.

I created a role with the desired permissions and added a user to this role. However, any login with the user on vCenter Mobile Access and the vSphere Client for iPad fails. The regular vSphere Client and VMware Workstation login fine with this user.

All services work fine with logging in as an Administrator. I would prefer not to have to make the tech an administrator to use the mobile clients.

The following are screenshots of the permissions assigned to the desired role:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/cwl5ecbpj/]
 [image: http://s14.postimg.org/wxqg7k4xt/esxi2.png]

Answer (score 1):

The minimum permissions should be the same as if using a normal client, as far as I know. I'll try and lab this out for you.

Answer (score 0):

With the iPad client you are quite limited in operations.
So VM power users or similar role could be appropriate.